# Trigger Google Analytics on redirect in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a short application form, where I capture some information, then redirect the user to a third party website where they complete the application.

I am using Google Analytics (and a Google conversion tracker) to monitor the hits on our site. Therefore I have to direct to a "conversion page" with the Analytics Javascript and a redirect. Unfortunately my javascript is not getting called.

How would I ensure the Javascript is called before the redirect happens?

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title></head><body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/Analytics.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/Analytics2.js"></script>

<!-- Google Code for Filling out Form Conversion Page -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    var google_conversion_id = 964293672;
    var google_conversion_language = "en";
    var google_conversion_format = "2";
    var google_conversion_color = "ffffff";
    var google_conversion_label = "H0y7CMi73wIQqOjnywM"; var google_conversion_value = 0;
    /* ]]> */
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js">
</script>

<noscript>
    <div style="display: inline;">
        <img height="1" width="1" style="border-style: none;" alt="" src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/964293672/?label=H0y7CMi73wIQqOjnywM&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0" />
    </div>
</noscript>
```

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
         Page.LoadComplete += new EventHandler(Page_LoadComplete);
    }
}
void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("https://anotherwebsite.com/c/transint?uri_b=ia_86894");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a third tracking script I need to add so I just used a JavaScript redirect in a jQuery docReady function.

I used window.location.replace(...), as it doesn't put the redirect page in browsing history.

Thanks for your input @Aristos.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the mobile code from Google Analytics and make an internal direct call to Google Analytics just before the redirect.

See the code example here.
http://code.google.com/mobile/analytics/docs/web/

from your analytic account download the **ga.aspx**  file and change it according to your account to call Google Analytics using code behind.

Here is that part of code that you need to focus.

```
string utmGifLocation = "http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif";

        // Construct the gif hit url.
        string utmUrl = utmGifLocation + "?" +
            "utmwv=" + Version +
            "&utmn=" + GetRandomNumber() +
            "&utmhn=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(domainName) +
            "&utmr=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(documentReferer) +
            "&utmp=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(documentPath) +
            "&utmac=" + account +
            "&utmcc=__utma%3D999.999.999.999.999.1%3B" +
            "&utmvid=" + visitorId +
            "&utmip=" + GetIP(GlobalContext.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]);

        SendRequestToGoogleAnalytics(utmUrl);



    private void SendRequestToGoogleAnalytics(string utmUrl)
    {
        try
        {
            WebRequest connection = WebRequest.Create(utmUrl);

            ((HttpWebRequest)connection).UserAgent = GlobalContext.Request.UserAgent;
            connection.Headers.Add("Accepts-Language",
                GlobalContext.Request.Headers.Get("Accepts-Language"));

            using (WebResponse resp = connection.GetResponse())
            {
                // Ignore response
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (GlobalContext.Request.QueryString.Get("utmdebug") != null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error contacting Google Analytics", ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

Maybe this is looks like Google hack, I do not know. The other way is to use the Google Analytics SDK to see there is there is any other official way to call it

http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/home.html